# How do WinForms controls inside WPF WindowsFormsHost remote?

Tags: wpf, winforms, remote-desktop, winforms-interop

Say, I have a WPF program with a Windows Forms control in "WindowsFormsHost" on some of its windows.

I use that program via Remote Desktop.

How will this control's graphics remote? Via GDI instructions as if it was WinForms app or as plain bitmaps like WPF does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a test. So, it remotes as GDI, very fast.